# Matching words with embedded pattern

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that matches a pattern, consisting of underscores and letters, with words. A letter matches itself; an underscore matches any character. For instance, the pattern `_a_`, `_at`, or `c_t_` would match `vacate` and `amplification` because it is embedded in them. I've implemented this when the pattern is a prefix, suffix, or is the same size as the word by iterating through every letter of each word and pattern and comparing them. However, I have no idea how to implement it when the pattern is embedded anywhere within the word. Any ideas (I'm using c++98)? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simple solution would be to loop the start position of the match from 0 to (wordlength-expressionlength), and try to match for each start position.

Comment: But doesn't that only work if the pattern is at the beginning of the word?

Comment: Take a look at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm. One-by-one approach (what KarstenKoop described) is called Naïve string search.

Answer (score 0):

You can match two words of equal length by writing a similar function to strcmp() that accepts underscores as always matching. You can then extend it to search anywhere in the "haystack" by call int it on haystack +0, haystack +1, haystack +2 etc, until you get to the point where you have less data in the haystack fits in the pattern.